Using CSS grid auto-fill that respects min-width
I am trying to lay items in a grid with columns of equals widths. I want the grid to have as many columns as possible while still honoring each item's min-width.
It seems that something like
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min-content, 1fr)) 

is what I would need however that combination is not supported.
Is there any way to achieve this? Here is what I tried; the text must not wrap, it is not known in advance neither is the number of items:
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="my-item">Some potentially pretty long text...</div>
  <div class="my-item">Some other text</div>
...
</div>

.my-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min-content, 1fr));  // illegal
    column-gap: 1rem;
    row-gap: 1rem;
}

.my-item {
    min-width: min-content;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

Thanks!

grid cheatsheet. does the "fit-content()" sizing function fit your needs?

I tried grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, fit-content(xx)); with xx = 50%, .5fr, 1fr ... and in all cases I have one item per line, always.

I think this has been answered here and sadly you are out of luck.

Good find, thanks, this indeed doesn't seem possible. I reverted to media queries to adapt grid-template-columns.
